# Reverse engineer 8 bit check sequence for old unkown protocol

Tags: serial-communication, crc

I am using an old piece of hardware which uses an RS485 serial interface. I'm trying to simulate slave node data but I don't have any documentation on the protocol and unfortunately the hardware is not supported any more.

I've got numerous examples of master and slave data for which I've tried to reverse engineer the check sequence but I've not found a match for the algorithm.

Master to Slave examples

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 A5
04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 A9
06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 AB
08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 AD
```

Slave to Master examples

```
80 00 24 F4 67 1E A3 00 00 00 00 3F 00 FB E6 F9 81 BB 17 D1
84 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 D8 3D 62 FC 6C 7C 84
86 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 39 7A 9A 05 77 77 6B
88 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 00 00 00 00 29 9E EA 45 76 78 21
```

It's clear the first 15 bytes for Master to Slave and first 19 bytes for Slave to Master is the data and the last byte is used as the check sequence. You can see the protocol uses the first byte as an address with the associated reply setting the most significant bit, though the addressing doesn't determine the error check byte algorithm it is included as part of the calculation.

My approach so far includes using the various online CRC and checksum calculators. I also tried to use reveng but have not managed to find a match. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sum all bytes, add A5.

Comment: Excellent that's it! Should have noticed with the first message all set to 00 was starring me in the face. Thank you :)