# Reverse Engineer 16 Bit error checking byte calculation

Tags: serial-communication, crc, checksum

Hello =) I am attempting to reverse engineer a communications protocol to some obsolete equipment. Communication happens on an RS485 line.

I have captured several exchanges and seem to have figured out a bit the structure.

What I am missing at the moment is to see how I would calculate the last 2 bytes which seem to be a CRC, Checksum, LRC,... some sort of Calculated bytes depending on the data.

This is a Master -> Slave Communication.
M: `Hex bytes sent by master`
Sx: `Hex Bytes replied by Slave x`

Serial Numbers of Slaves:
S1: F376150801196
S2: F306103101122
S3: F306093001029

- Broadcasting message to Discover devices
- M: `ff 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 13 00 02 00 00 18 01`
- S1: `fe 00 f3 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ac 04 a5 02`
- S2: `fe 00 f3 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 62 04 5b 02`
- S3: `fe 00 f3 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 04 fe 01`

Devices getting enumerated :

- M:  `ff 00 f3 02 ac 04 00 00 00 1b 00 00 00 00 bf 02`
- S1: `fe 00 f3 02 ac 04 38 30 35 31 36 37 ac 04 8e 04`
- M:  `ff 00 f3 03 ac 04 00 00 00 1b 00 00 00 00 c0 02`
- S1: `fe 00 f3 03 ac 04 38 30 35 31 36 37 ac 04 8f 04`
- M:  `ff 00 f3 16 ac 04 00 00 00 1b 00 00 ac 04 83 03`
- S1: `fe 00 f3 16 ac 04 38 30 35 31 36 37 ac 04 a2 04`
- M:  `ff 00 f3 02 62 04 00 00 00 1b 00 00 00 00 75 02`
- S2: `fe 00 f3 02 62 04 31 33 30 31 36 30 62 04 ea 03`
- M:  `ff 00 f3 03 62 04 00 00 00 1b 00 00 00 00 76 02`
- S2: `fe 00 f3 03 62 04 31 33 30 31 36 30 62 04 eb 03`
- M:  `ff 00 f3 16 62 04 00 00 00 1b 00 00 62 04 ef 02`
- S2: `fe 00 f3 16 62 04 31 33 30 31 36 30 62 04 fe 03`
- M:  `ff 00 f3 02 05 04 00 00 00 1b 00 00 00 00 18 02`
- S3: `fe 00 f3 02 05 04 30 33 39 30 36 30 05 04 37 03`
- M:  `ff 00 f3 03 05 04 00 00 00 1b 00 00 00 00 19 02`
- S3: `fe 00 f3 03 05 04 30 33 39 30 36 30 05 04 38 03`
- M:  `ff 00 f3 16 05 04 00 00 00 1b 00 00 05 04 35 02`
- S3: `fe 00 f3 16 05 04 30 33 39 30 36 30 05 04 4b 03`

---

Acknowledgement of recieved command from different slaves to the commands of move slave from Master

- S1: `fe 00 f3 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ac 04 e2 02`
- S2: `fe 00 f3 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 62 04 98 02`
- S3: `fe 00 f3 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 04 3b 02`

Commands, acknowledged by the acknowledge command of each respective Slave accordingly

- S1 Stop Movement:
- M: `ff fb f3 41 00 00 90 01 c2 01 00 03 ac 04 35 05`
- S2 Stop Movement:
- M: `ff fb f3 41 ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 62 04 96 04`
- S3 Stop Movement:
- M: `ff fb f3 41 ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 05 04 39 04`
- S3 Go Right `ff fb f3 41 ff 01 00 00 00 00 00 03 05 04 3a 04`
- S3 Go Left  `ff fb f3 41 ff 02 00 00 00 00 00 03 05 04 3b 04`
- S3 Go Down  `ff fb f3 41 ff 03 00 00 00 00 00 03 05 04 3c 04`
- S3 Go Up    `ff fb f3 41 ff 04 00 00 00 00 00 03 05 04 3d 04`
- S2 Go Right `ff fb f3 41 ff 01 00 00 00 00 00 03 62 04 97 04`
- S2 Go Left  `ff fb f3 41 ff 02 00 00 00 00 00 03 62 04 98 04`
- S2 Go Down  `ff fb f3 41 ff 03 00 00 00 00 00 03 62 04 99 04`
- S2 Go Up    `ff fb f3 41 ff 04 00 00 00 00 00 03 62 04 9a 04`
- S1 Go Right `ff fb f3 41 ff 01 90 01 c2 01 00 03 ac 04 35 06`
- S1 Go Left  `ff fb f3 41 ff 02 90 01 c2 01 00 03 ac 04 36 06`
- S1 Go Down  `ff fb f3 41 ff 03 90 01 c2 01 00 03 ac 04 37 06`
- S1 Go Up    `ff fb f3 41 ff 04 90 01 c2 01 00 03 ac 04 38 06`

S3 Go to

- 400 , 450 : `ff fb f3 41 ff 05 90 01 c2 01 00 03 05 04 92 05`
- 401 , 450 : `ff fb f3 41 ff 05 91 01 c2 01 00 03 05 04 93 05`
- 402 , 450 : `ff fb f3 41 ff 05 92 01 c2 01 00 03 05 04 94 05`
- 403 , 450 : `ff fb f3 41 ff 05 93 01 c2 01 00 03 05 04 95 05`
- 404 , 450 : `ff fb f3 41 ff 05 94 01 c2 01 00 03 05 04 96 05`
- 405 , 450 : `ff fb f3 41 ff 05 95 01 c2 01 00 03 05 04 97 05`
- 406 , 450 : `ff fb f3 41 ff 05 96 01 c2 01 00 03 05 04 98 05`
- 407 , 450 : `ff fb f3 41 ff 05 97 01 c2 01 00 03 05 04 99 05`
- 408 , 450 : `ff fb f3 41 ff 05 98 01 c2 01 00 03 05 04 9a 05`
- 409 , 450 : `ff fb f3 41 ff 05 99 01 c2 01 00 03 05 04 9b 05`
- 410 , 450 : `ff fb f3 41 ff 05 9a 01 c2 01 00 03 05 04 9c 05`

---

From my observations the Structure I have the following identified:

`ff    fb    f3    41 ff 05 9a 01 c2 01 00 03 05     04     9c     05`

byte1 byte2 byte3 --------------------------------- byte13 byte14 byte15 byte16

- bytes 13 and 14 are to identify the specific device which is in a multi-drop network for whom the command is for. It is the last 5 numbers of the serial number represented in Hexadecimal.

  - 0405 -> 01029 <- S3: F306093001029
  - 0462 -> 01122 <- S2: F306103101122
  - 04ac -> 01196 <- S1: F376150801196
- bytes 15 and 16 are the calculated ones, which I am trying to figure out how they get calculated.

---

I have been manually attempting to calculate and compare several 16 bit CRCs and also tried running several frames through [Reveng](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/) with out much luck, no models ever get found.

---

Any help and insights would be greatly apreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So, after reviewing [This following Stack Overflow Question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/20748/2490)

I opened up an excel and made some tests and effectively

Sum of all bytes is the calculation

- Hex  `ff  00  00  04  00  00  00  00  00  13  00  02  00  00  18  01`
- Dec  `255 0   0   4   0   0   0   0   0   19  0   2   0   0`

  - Sum of all in Decimal = **280** --> Respresented in Hex `0118`

Sometimes we search for too complicated answers to simple things.

Thanks anyway for having a look.